# Always asking for run time permissions in some marshmallow devices

Tags: android

I created a android application which asks for some runtime permissions on start! But in some marshmallow devices even if users grants the permissions , the app again ask for permissions after app start again or MainActivity is  loaded! I dont know why! it works without any issues in nogout,oreo etc. My Client has a custom made china device.. I tried this in genymotion and i got the same issue!

I request permissions like;

```
 String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES,android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA};
       Log.e("PERMISSSION ADDED",String.valueOf(hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)));
        if(!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
        }


public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I logged the value! Its always is false after app/activity restarts!

How could i solve this? Please help!!

**UPDATE**

When i removed I `Manifest.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES` the issue was fixed.. But as i need to install packages by downloading apk from URL i will be needing INSTALL_PACKAGES right?

Comment: Where is your onRequestPermissionsResult method?

Comment: @Grisgram. I didn't do anything after granting permissions! So i didn't use  `onRequestPermissionsResult`

Comment: Well, you have to... You need an action code and only call super.onPermissionResult if another action than your own arrives. Catch your own actioncode and do not call the super. (At least that's what my apps do and I never had a problem like yours)